# nginx/PHP GET works but POST doesn't

Tags: php, post, nginx

Using GET works, but POST doesn't with nginx & PHP. Am I missing something in the nginx configuration?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your factgi_params file contains `fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;`, `fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;` and `fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;` ? If so, how do you test that it doesn't work ?

Comment: I'm using the following code:
<script>

function editAddr(){

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test2.php',
        data: {
            address:'' + 1 + ''
        },
        success: function(content) {

            alert(content);

        }

    });

}

editAddr();

</script> Replacing POST with GET works. test2.php contains: echo $_POST['address'];

Comment: are you sure? Regular web pages usually work with GET method.. You could create a simple form (with POST method) to test if it's working or not.. Or even better use POSTMAN chrome extension to test it.. I don't think nginx is causing this problem.

Comment: Ok, I just tested the form post and it works. But why is the jquery ajax code not working? With developer tools I see the action parameter is being sent with value 1, but $_POST['address'] is empty. This same code works on Apache.

Comment: @Antoni You can't send POST request to the regualar page by simply setting the POST keywod. May be [this](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php) can help you

Comment: I'm not using PHP to send a POST request. I'm using Jquery/AJAX.

Comment: BTW, I'm using HTTPS.

Comment: @Antoni nginx doesn't send POST request to static page or url, [this] may help you if the page you're requesting is static.. PS:// you should send POST request if you want to post something to DB..

Answer (score -2):

It seems Jquery was the problem, updating to the latest version solved it.
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: interesting solution.. But I didn't understand how that old version worked with Apache?...

Comment: Me neither, it's very weird. I used jquery 1.8.2, updating to 1.8.3 works too.